# Basic manual authentication in Laravel 11

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-11

I'm trying to implement manual authentication in Laravel. However, after entering the correct username and password on my login page, it doesn't redirect to the dashboard page; instead, it returns to the login page.

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request) {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'username' => ['required'],
            'password' => ['required']
        ]);

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ])->onlyInput('email');
    }
    public function register(Request $request){
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required'],
            'username' => ['required'],
            'password' => ['required']
        ]);

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $credentials['name'];
        $user->username = $credentials['username'];
        $user->password = Hash::make($credentials['password']);
    
        $user->save();
    
        return redirect('login');
        
    }
}
```

Route:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('login');
})->name('login');

Route::get('/register', function () {
    return view('register'); 
})->name('register');

Route::post('/login', [UserController::class, 'login'])->name('login_process');
Route::post('/register', [UserController::class, 'register'])->name('register_process');
```

```
namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
            'password' => 'hashed',
        ];
    }
}
```

I've tried creating a new model, but the problem still exists.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserAuth extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'password'
    ];
}
```

Comment: where is dashboard route? did you define?